# Are the in-built sharesmb / sharensfs options in ZFS on Linux special/better?

Tags: samba, nfs, cifs, zfsonlinux

While reading through the [man page of zfs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/zfs) I noticed the `sharesmb` and `sharenfs` options. Are they thin wrappers over samba/smb/cifs/nfs provided by the underlying Linux system, or special/optimised code baked right into ZFS? Is there anything peculiar about ZFS (at a low-level) due to which one *should* use the in-built sharesmb/sharenfs options instead of standard Linux tools?

Comment: The man page says exactly how both of those options work. But the page you linked to is not the current ZFS on Linux man page. In fact, it's not even from Linux at all. Try reading the live man page instead.

Comment: smb https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/blob/master/lib/libshare/smb.c#L239 nfs https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/blob/master/lib/libshare/nfs.c#L240

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton -- I didn't realise I was reading wrong man page all this time!

Comment: Thanks @Zoredache. So, it's just a thin wrapper. I guess it's better to set-up file-sharing outside of ZFS so that one knows exactly what configuration has been used.

Comment: The OpenZFS leadership mtg just discussed this very topic:
https://youtu.be/Li8Z08KZvg8?t=189